# Embedding Google Drive folder in website stopped working

Tags: wordpress, iframe, google-drive-api

I have had the following iframe code for embedding a folder on my Wordpress website (http://topnotchcanines.com/tnc_events/akc-dec/) for about 11 months and it has worked beautifully.  Yesterday I had a client tell me my folder is not displaying.  I am now getting a message in the lower left "waiting for clients6.google.com".  I have given them a link directly to the google folder since I have an event coming soon. But..  really need to get this working again.

Any advice ?

What I have discovered:
   If I am logged into my Drive account everything displays nicely.  If I am not logged in,  I get the above message.  Yes the folder is shared with "Anyone with the link can view"  
   The problem occurs in Chrome, Edge and Safari on my ipad.

Has Google changed something ??

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection to Google server, clear browser cache, try on different devices. I can see your files even in Incognito mode (not logged in any Google accounts).

[image]